# not overriding css transform style using js?

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, transform

I've got different elements each with a different transform property,

```
.one{transform: rotateY(10deg)}
.two{transform: rotateY(20deg)}
 //etc.
```

and I'm tryng to add a translateZ (through javascript) to these transform properties.

As expected adding such a value automatically overrides the pre-existing property .

Is there an easy way to get this done?

(as a workaround I thought about using `transform-origin` but I'd rather avoid that if it's possible)

Comment: could you post a minimal code example that shows the issue?

Comment: There's always a way, but setting a new `transform` inline overrides the previous `transform`, you need to set one transform that contains both the rotate and the translate, but getting the rotate values in javascript isn't easy either, as `transform` returns a matrix.

Comment: I'll try changing code to integrate transform-origin

Answer (score 1):

As long as you're trying to do it only once you could just concat those string like

```
newTransform = element.style.getPropertyValue("transform") + "translateZ(..px)"
```

If you're trying to do it multiple times you'd need to check and probably replace within your style-string if there's already a `translateZ` value.

Comment: I'm looking into storing the value - manipulate it - and style.transform it back to element